# WIndow.open wrong character encoding

Tags: javascript

If I attempt to open a popup window, and set the character encoding with a meta tag, the new window ignores the tag. The HTML only displays correctly if I manually set the encoding on the new window to UTF-8.

```
var headerPopupContent = '<head>'
            + '<meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">'
            + '<title>Chat</title>'
            + '<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">'
            + '<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style-rtl.css">'
            + '</head>';
    var chatBoxContent = $('#popup-box').html();
    var footerPopupContent = '<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>'
            + '<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>';
    var win = window.open('', '', 'width=350, height=430, top=50, left=50, resizable=1, scrollbars=1');
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write(headerPopupContent + chatBoxContent + footerPopupContent);
    win.document.close();
```

Comment: You may want to ensure that you wrap your content with the appropriate `<!DOCTYPE html>` ,`<html>` and `<body>` tags when applicable. This may help resolve some of your encoding issues, but if not, it's certainly not a bad idea for standards-sake.

Comment: Open the network tab in the developer tools of your favorite browser and see the encoding used in the petition, instead of rendered html. You'll see the real charset used by the browser

Comment: Does `chatBoxContent` contain valid URF8?

Comment: @RionWilliams it's ok, your page is not treated as HTML5 since your doctype it's not correct. In html 4.01 doesn't exist the `<meta charset>` tag

Comment: why you dont use append()? Isn't it awkward the way you do?

Comment: Please escape the end script tags if the code is not in an external js file: `var footerPopupContent = '<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"><\/script>'
            + '<script src="assets/js/script.js"><\/script>';` - without the script it seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xoxwcrtc/

Comment: The calling page has the meta tag set as UTF-8. The HTML is pulled straight from there, and copied to the new window.

Comment: msplungjan - I see that removing the script fixes the problem - but I need the script. How do I fix it that I can use the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please escape the end script tags since they mess with the existing script unless the code is in an external js file:

```
var footerPopupContent = '<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"><\/script>' 
+ '<script src="assets/js/script.js"><\/script>';
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xoxwcrtc/)

Also `win.document.open();` is not needed since the first document.write will open the document. In the old days, it was thought that document.open took a mime type as parameter, but I believe it never worked.

> Also, an automatic document.open() call happens when document.write() is called after the page has loaded, but that's not defined in the W3C specification.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the paths to backslashes, and it works.

Thanks  mplungjan

```
var footerPopupContent = '<script src="assets\js\jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>'
            + '<script src="assets\js\script.js"></script>'
```